USB 2.5 GB NIC not working in 24.04 on a Raspberry 5
I have a  ASUSTek USB 2.5G LAN adapter (USB-C2500) which is not working on my Rasberry Pi 5  running Ubuntu 24.04 Lite.
When I do an inxi -n I get the following output (MACs redacted):
Network:
  Device-1: Raspberry Pi RP1 PCIe 2.0 South Bridge driver: rp1
  IF: wlan0 state: down mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
  Device-2: ASUSTek USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN driver: usb-storage type: USB
  IF-ID-1: eth0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Odd thing, while the device is appearing, it is showing up as a usb-storage device?
I have already added the file 50-usb-realtek-net.rules into the /etc/udev/rules.d/  folder following the advice here - after confirming  the most current version of the contents for that file downloaded from here and the one in the post linked to above are the same - but still no love.
Also, yes, I did a sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade,
Finally, of note, the same Raspberry PI and ASUS device work just fine when the Raspberry Pi is running the current version of Raspberry OS.  The problem only appears when the Raspberry is running Ubuntu 24.04 Lite.
Any advice or insights would be appreciated.
